# fixed error in making exe file using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, py2exe, cx-freeze

I d like to make an EXE file from a Python script for windows 8 and 10, I am using python 2.7. i  tried  py2exe and cx_Freeze, but nothing  has worked. I asked question about my problem  -[py2exe write data to file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135202/py2exe-write-data-to-file-not-working), but no one had answered it.

## !/usr/bin/python2.7

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

url2 = 'http://www.autobody.ru/kuzovnoy-remont/'
urls1 = ['http://www.autobody.ru/kuzovnoy-remont/']
urls=['http://www.autobody.ru/kuzovnoy-remont/','http://www.autobody.ru/optics/','http://www.autobody.ru/tuning/','http://www.autobody.ru/cooling/','http://www.autobody.ru/mechanics/','http://www.autobody.ru/mirrors/']
for url in urls:
 html = get_html(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 mydivs = soup.findAll('a',class_="banners_images")
 urls = []

 for i in mydivs:
    ur = (i.get('href'))
    ur = 'http://www.autobody.ru' + str(ur)
    urls.append(ur.encode('utf8'))

 images = []
 heads = []
 artic = []
 atrib = []
 price = []
 a1=[]
 a2=[]
 a3=[]
 with open('/home/arator/1.csv', 'a') as f:        # Open the file in binary mode for Python 2.x
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # writes "byte order mark" UTF-8 signature
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for i in urls:
        html = get_html(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        head = soup.find('h1').get_text()
        heads.append(head.encode('utf8'))

        image = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'detimg'})]
        image1 = 'http://www.autobody.ru'+image[0]
        images.append(image1.encode('utf8'))

        price1 = soup.find('div', class_='price').get_text()
        price1 = re.sub(r"c",r"p", price1)
        price.append(price1.encode('utf8'))

        zo=soup.find('table', class_='tech').find_all('tr')
        artic.append(zo[0].get_text().strip().encode('utf8'))
        atrib.append(zo[1].get_text().strip().encode('utf8'))
        a1.append(zo[2].get_text().strip().encode('utf8'))
        try:
          a2.append(zo[3].get_text().strip().encode('utf8'))
        except:
            a2.append(1)
        writer.writerows(zip(*[heads, price, artic, images,atrib,a1,a2,urls]))
        print(1)
```

Does anyone knows the way to make it script worked ?Is where any easy way to make script to exe application in another way&

Comment: use pyinstaller